# "530 Authentication required" SMTP and I don't know why

Tags: java, email, smtp, smtpclient

I wrote an emailSender with the javax.mail library. I don't know where my mistake is, because in the video from where the code is it worked.

The Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkpHQD9e5hc&t=1630s

I also saw the other question on this website to this topic but no solution of these worked for my problem

Code:

```
public class MailSender {

    protected Session mailSession;

    public void login(String smtpHost, String smtpPort, String username, String password) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        };

        this.mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        System.out.println("Eingeloggt.");
    }

    public void send(String senderMail, String senderName, String receiverAddresses, String subject, String message, String username, String password)
            throws MessagingException, IllegalStateException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (mailSession == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Du musst dich zuerst einloggen (login()-Methode)");
        }

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
        msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
        msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderMail, senderName));
        msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(senderMail, false));
        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setText(message, "UTF-8");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(receiverAddresses, false));

        System.out.println("Versende E-Mail...");
        Transport.send(msg, username, password);
        System.out.println("E-Mail versendet.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is from another email server installed on your local system:

If its "530 SMTP authentication is required" then POPcon tries to reach your Exchange Server on IP port 25 (SMTP) but instead this other mail server answers with this particular error message. You need to either remove hMailServer from the system and restart Exchange or move one of the two servers to  a different local IP port since both can't coexist on port 25. You can select the IP port that POPcon tries to reach on the EXCHANGE configuration page in the POPcon configuration.

Comment: But it isn't "530 SMTP authentication is required".